# PHP - Making transparent background from white

Tags: php, image, gd

I have a function which does the job to remove the white background to white but when I try to copy the new image onto a new image with *imagecopy* the image still has the white background. If someone could tell me where am going wrong I will be greatfull since am frustrated now since this is supposed to be working. and also when I open the image created in paint it still has a white background.
the outputted image is transparent but on copy it has a white background.
Thanks in advance
here is the code

```
public function transparent_background($filename, $color, $image)
{
  $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($image); 
    $colors = explode(',', $color);
    $remove = imagecolorallocate($img, $colors[0], $colors[1], $colors[2]);
    imagecolortransparent($img, $remove);
    imagepng($img, $filename,0);
    return $img;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a typing mistake,

It is wrong see the third parameter

```
public function transparent_background($filename, $color,$imgage)
```

Try

```
public function transparent_background($filename, $color,$image)
```

Comment: That was me trying to type it here. There problems still is there, there is white background on copy\